# refresh div tag

Tags: html, refresh

i have my index.php to load another page (playing.php) and refresh the contents of that loaded page. It does its job for a while and then the page goes blank,then returns back with page content.Not sure what is going on with the code heres the link :[mobile website](http://m.tamilmelisai.com)
Please right click for the source code

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajaxSetup(
    {
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#content').hide();
            $('#loading').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#content').show();
        },
        success: function() {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#content').show();
        }
    });
    var $container = $("#content");
    $container.load("playing.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        $container.load('playing.php');
    }, 40000);
});})(jQuery);
```

`

and to call the contents

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content"></div>
<img src="images/loading.gif" id="loading" alt="loading" style="display:none;" />
```

`

Comment: Could you please provide the code here instead, the php code.

Comment: All I wanted to see was the below result. Is it possible to load only the contents of div instead calling for .load('another page')
ex:Div1 = #contents (no refresh required)

Div2 = #contents2 (no loading of another page require refresh every xx seconds)